# Trying to make the program stop running by inputting a string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make my javascript program stop running if the user inputs the string "END" and then go straight to the output. I just tried putting the break , but it ouputs undefined. So far i have this:

```
var name = new Array(40);
var mark = new Array(40);
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var error = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxynzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYNZ.\'- ";

for(i; i<3; i++){
  name[i]=prompt("Enter student\'s name, allowed characters: [a-zA-Z.\'- ]");
  if (name[i] == 'END'){
    alert('No input. \n Goodbye.');
  }
  break;
  mark[i]=prompt('Enter student\'s mark');
}

var student = mark.concat(name);
student.sort();
alert(student[3]);
```

The program is supposed to ask user for student name and their mark. then print out the student with the highest mark. user can type END to stop the program. And the name can allow the characters found in var error. I am also having problems implementing the var error into my program

Comment: Sorry i should explain what the program is supposed to do. The program is supposed to ask user for student name and their mark. then print out the student with the highest mark. user can type END to stop the program. And the name can allow the characters found in var error. I am also having problems implementing the var error into my program.

Comment: Edit your original question with the info in your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a `break` statement: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break

```
if (name[i] === 'END') {
    alert('No input. \n Goodbye.');
    break; // Will exit the loop
}
```

Secondly there seems to be some weirdness surrounding the name `name` which I was unaware of until trying this right now.

```
>>> var names = new Array(40)
undefined
>>> names
[undefined × 40]
>>> names[0] = "hello"
"hello"
>>> names
["hello", undefined × 39]


>>> var name = new Array(40)
undefined
>>> name
",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"
>>> name[0] = "hello"
"hello"
>>> name
",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"
```

So maybe change your `name` array to be called something else? (`names` is a better name anyway since it's a number of names and not just a single name).

Turns out the global `name` variable is special because it refers to the "window name" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.name), which is why you're seeing that behaviour.

Also in your current code, you have your `break` statement outside the `if`, so it will break every time regardless of the input. You want the `break` inside the `if` so it will only break on that specific input.

Comment: I tried break, but it didn't end the loop. I also tried putting break after the if loop, but the output says undefined instead of "No input"

Comment: Did you see the alert? Did you type exactly "END", in capitals?

Comment: i did type END. no the alert didn't show up. It did stop the program

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your loop to end after seeing "END"?  Just use break.

Also, what is your last line supposed to do?

Comment: Considering the `break` statement was already answered,this should be a comment

Comment: I am sorry, I am not as fast as some people here :)  I.e. I didn't see the other answer before I had submitted mine